# Kernel compiling help

Tags: kernel, hard-drive, compiling

I was compiling the kernel 3.2 when it was taken more time than the walkthrough indicated. So I cancelled it, realizing that it took 5 gb of hard drive space. I deleted all the kernel folders downloaded but that still didn't recover the space. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the output of df? Also the relevant bits from your bash history - downloading, extracting, compiling and deleting.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know what "df" stands for.

Comment: "disk free". Type it at a console to see your free disk space. Generally "df -h" to get it in "human" form.

Comment: 'Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5              22G   11G   11G  49% /
udev                  866M  4.0K  866M   1% /dev
tmpfs                 350M  796K  349M   1% /run
none                  5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                  875M  1.7M  873M   1% /run/shm
'

Comment: i 'think' when you abort compilation the temporary stuff, not sure if in /tmp or /var/tmp resides there. and yes, kernel compilation can take a while, depends on how much you want to built into the kernel (or as a module) and how fast your computer is.

Comment: I've known (on smaller/slower machines) kernel compilations to run overnight. Stuff in tmp (since it is mounted with tmpfs), will be gone when you next reboot. Now - which of the devices above was the space used on?

Comment: I do have a "slower" laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By **delete** did you mean from the GUI file browser or **rm -rf** from the console? If it's the former than all those files are in the trash and you need to empty it to reclaim the space. The build is self-contained, if you truly wiped out the git/build tree then everything associated with the build is gone.

This is the procedure I use to build kernels:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Dev/QuickBuildLocal

Most users usually don't have a good reason to build their own kernel, unless you're into tweaking that is in which case have a blast :-).